# Failed to start LSB: Starts and stops the iSCSI software target

Tags: crash

My server crashes a few minutes after startup, which I found in the /var/log/boot.log:

```
[  OK  ] Started LSB: disk temperature monitoring daemon.
[FAILED] Failed to start LSB: Starts and stops the iSCSI software target.
See 'systemctl status iscsitarget.service' for details.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: VirtualBox Linux kernel module.
[  OK  ] Started OpenVPN connection to server.
         Starting Permit User Sessions...
[  OK  ] Started Permit User Sessions.
         Starting Hold until boot process finishes up...
[  OK  ] Started MySQL Community Server.
[  OK  ] Started LSB: This service starts and stops VMware services.
         Starting LSB: This services starts and stops the Workstation as a Server daemon....
[  OK  ] Started LSB: This services starts and stops the Workstation as a Server daemon..
[FAILED] Failed to start vboxadd.service.
See 'systemctl status vboxadd.service' for details.
         Starting vboxadd-service.service...
         Starting Light Display Manager...
[FAILED] Failed to start vboxadd-service.service.
See 'systemctl status vboxadd-service.service' for details.
```

I can access it through ssh before the server crashes, and everything looks normal.

How can I solve this problem?

The server temporarily returned to normal after I executed the following command, but I don't know why.

```
  933  systemctl stop vboxadd.service
  934  systemctl disable vboxadd-service.service
  935  sudo systemctl stop vboxadd-service.service
  936  sudo systemctl disable vboxadd.service
  937  sudo apt purge virtualbox*
  938  shutdown -r now
  939  svn co https://svn.code.sf.net/p/iscsitarget/code/ iscsitarget
  940  apt-get update
  941  apt-get upgrade
  942  apt-get -f install
  943  apt-get update
  944  apt-get install --reinstall iscsitarget-dkms
  945  systemctl enable iscsitarget
  946  systemctl restart iscsitarget
  947  systemctl status iscsitarget.service
  948  journalctl -xe
  949  vim /usr/src/aufs-4.9+20161219/dkms.conf
  950  apt-get remove -y docker-engine
  951  apt-get install -y docker-engine
  952  uname -r
  953  docker-ce
  954  apt-get install -y docker-engine
  955  cat /etc/os-release
  956  uname -a
  957  dpkg --list | grep linux-image
  958  dpkg --list | grep linux-headers
  959  dpkg --list | grep raspberrypi-
  960  apt full-upgrade
  961  apt-get update
  962  apt full-upgrade
  963  sudo apt autoremove
  964  apt-get install -f
  965  dpkg --configure -a
  966  yy
  967  y
  968  yy
  969  y
  970  apt-get install -f
  971  ls
  972  sudo apt autoremove
  973  sudo apt -f autoremove
  974  apt full-upgrade
  975  apt -f full-upgrade
  976  sudo apt-get install -f && sudo dpkg --configure -a
  977  apt-get update && sudo apt-get -y upgrade && sudo apt-get -y dist-upgrade
  978  apt-get update
  979  apt-get -y upgrade
  980  apt-get -y upgrade -f
  981  apt-get -y dist-upgrade
  982  apt-get -y dist-upgrade -f
```

Comment: What version of Ubuntu?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04.5 LTS

Comment: Linux b8311-PowerEdge-T630 4.15.0-140-generic #144-Ubuntu SMP Fri Mar 19 14:12:35 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Comment: I found a temporary solution, but I don't know why